# Change uitextfield background color to grey iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I use [txtfld setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greyColor]] but the compiler sais may not respond and crashes not working!

How can i make the background color grey?

Comment: How is txtfld declared and to what class object is it assigned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a thread that indicates there is a problem if the field has rounded corners

http://icodeblog.com/2010/01/04/uitextfield-a-complete-api-overview/